# Scroll the content inside a scrollable div when clicking an element

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, overflow

I have a DIV which is limited in height, and has a scrollable overflow. I would like to add two manual scroll links that when they are clicked, the content inside the DIV scrolls up or down.

CSS

```
#inner {
   max-height: 400px;
   overflow: scroll;
}
```

JS

```
function scrolldown() {
   document.getElementById('#inner').scrollTop -= 10;
}
function scrollup() {
   document.getElementById('#inner').scrollTop += 10;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="inner">
    Looooong content here
</div>
<a href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:scrollup();">
    <img src="up.png"/>
</a>
<a href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:scrolldown();">
    <img src="down.png"/>
</a>
```

However it does not really work ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use CSS selector in `getElementById`.

```
function scrolldown() {
    document.getElementById('inner').scrollTop -= 10;
}
function scrollup() {
    document.getElementById('inner').scrollTop += 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You used a double selector, `getElementById` does not need the `#` in its argument. And if you put the javascript between the `<head>` tags it should work fine.

```
function scrolldown() {
    document.getElementById('inner').scrollTop -= 10;
}
function scrollup() {
    document.getElementById('inner').scrollTop += 10;
}
```